# iOS Facebook API - How to populate the UIWebView

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get just a piece of information from Facebook, but I don't want to use the default Facebook API (because it doesn't allow you to auto-populate the text field when doing a feed).

So, I'm creating a custom view that has the text view and the share and cancel buttons, but I want to show information about the app, as well.  I'm not sure how to do this.

The image below is what the FBDialog (part of the native FB API). What I want is to show ONLY the information in the red box. This is a mixture of manually specified parameters, as well as something coming from FB about the app itself ("via  ...").

So, my question is, how can pull the "via  for iOS" from FB (notice that is not manual in the code, whereas everything else in the red box is) and put it into a uiwebview (I'm assuming that is the only way)? Or can I even get **just** that information and display the info without specifying an action like "feed" (which would also bring in the text box from FB)?

Here is the code that makes this dialog pop up:

```
    currentAPICall = kDialogFeedUser;
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

// The action links to be shown with the post in the feed
NSArray* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       @"Get Started",@"name",@"http://m.facebook.com/apps/hackbookios/",@"link", nil], nil];
NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
// Dialog parameters
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"I'm using the Hackbook for iOS app", @"name",
                               @"Hackbook for iOS.", @"caption",
                               @"Check out Hackbook for iOS to learn how you can make your iOS apps social using Facebook Platform.", @"description",
                               @"http://m.facebook.com/apps/hackbookios/", @"link",
                               @"http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/img/facebook_icon_large.png", @"picture",
                               actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                               nil];

HackbookAppDelegate *delegate = (HackbookAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  
[[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed"
        andParams:params
      andDelegate:self];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out a real hack to make it work, but so far, it's the only answer I've got. If anyone has a better answer, please post, and I'll mark it as the correct one.

I ended up creating a UIView that contains a number of things. Essentially, I still use what you see in the picture above, but I cover the top portion so that I only see the bottom area that I care about.

From bottom layer to top layer, this is what my XIB file has:

1. The main UIView -- the container that is linked to a class
2. A UIWebView to contain the FB feed
3. A UIView with a white background (or whatever to match the color of the UIView in #1--I'm using white b/c that's what Facebook uses in their response HTML in the UIWebView). This white background goes behind the UITextView (#5) and UIView "border" view (#4). I do this so that I can "block out" the upper portion of the response from Facebook, and only show the bottom portion (in red outline in pick above).
4. A UIView to go behind the UIText view - gray background 2px wider and 2px taller than the UITextView to give a 1px border effect on all edges of the UITextView. Yes, I'm sure there is a better way, but this is all one big hack, so I hacked away. :)
5. A UITextView so that I can pre-populate the text; this text view has a background color that should match the background color of the UIView in #1 above. I did this so I could create the gray border effect without having to draw. So in my case, the UITextView has a white background, and so does the main view in #1.

Now, in code (in my case, I'm modifying the default behavior of a kit that does most of the heavy lifting) I do the following:

1. Set up the FB action links and FB parameters
2. Check to see if the app is authorized to use Facebook (if not, then display a different dialog)
3. Instantiate the class behind the new XIB file I created
4. **This one is important--Generate the URL by using code from the Facebook API (there is literally a method for this: `+ (NSURL*)generateURL:(NSString*)baseURL params:(NSDictionary*)params`
5. Make a URL request object: `NSMutableURLRequest* theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:_loadingURL];`
6. Load the UIWebView in XIB and class behind: `[rootView.webView loadRequest:theRequest];`
7. Finally, show the view!

I hope this helps someone else. It really shouldn't have been this much of a pain. In fact, Facebook really should allow consumers of the API pre-fill the text box, just like they used to, but that's a separate rant that could keep me off topic for a while.

FYI, this is the final look of my view:

[image]